# Assertion Error in keras

Tags: keras, keras-layer

I am trying to write a GAN in keras but I am getting this assertion error while running it. After searching I found out the most likely cause of the problem is an old version theano. I updated theano to the latest github development version **0.9.0beta1** but still I am getting the same error.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from keras.optimizers import SGD

print "Setting up decoder"
D = Sequential()
D.add(Dense(100, input_dim=100, activation='relu'))
D.add(Dropout(0.5))
D.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
D.add(Dropout(0.5))
D.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.1)
D.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd)

print "Setting up generator"
G = Sequential()
G.add(Dense(1, input_dim=1, activation='relu'))
G.add(Dropout(0.5))
G.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
G.add(Dropout(0.5))
G.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.1)
G.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd)

print "Setting up combined net"
gen_dec = Sequential()
gen_dec.add(G)
D.trainable=False
gen_dec.add(D)
gen_dec.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd)
gen_dec.summary()
```

The problem happens in this section `gen_dec.add(D)`

```
assert input_shape[-1] and input_shape[-1] == self.input_dim
AssertionError
```

Comment: What assertion error? You didn't include it in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a typo in your code... Please change the last layer of the Generator from:

```
G.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

to:

```
G.add(Dense(100, activation='sigmoid'))
```

I guess you didn't want your generator to produce only 1 pixel since your discriminator takes 100 inputs.

The error came from the fact that your first model outputs a tensor with shape `(batch_size, 1)` and your second model input takes a input shape of `(batch_size, 100)`. Hence the assert error.

It's compiling on my laptop now.

Comment: I am trying to port this pytorch code in keras https://github.com/devnag/pytorch-generative-adversarial-networks/blob/master/gan_pytorch.py here the author uses 1 input size for generator and 100 input size for discriminator.

Comment: Im talking about output of the generator here, not the input.

Comment: In that code they use some function to generate the data. See preprocess function in the code. You cant copy an algorithm and skip some parts like that :) the fix im proposing

Comment: the fix im proposing is good too, the only difference is that it uses an implicit distribution. The link you provided uses an explicit distribution*

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. It compiled what you ment by implicit/explicit distiribution?

Comment: In the code of the link, the preprocess function uses a distribtion function explicitely defined to generate the data from the output of Generator.

Comment: With the fix i proposed, the neural networks learns the data distribution itself, not using a Normal law or anything